# Read Drush config file

Tags: 7, drush

I am creting a module with Drush integration. My challenge now is how to read the Drush config file in `~/.drush/myconfig.drushrc.php`.

I tried `drush_load_config_file` but it is not working.

`drush_load_config_file($context, _drush_config_file($context, 'deployment'));`

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? drushrc of user's choice will already be executed before your module's function will start. This should require absolutely no action on your part.

Comment: My goal there is to read the variable value set by user. Example are `$options['repository']` and `$options['docroot']`. Those are user defined values so I need to know what are the values for the module to do its function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you are looking in the wrong place to integrate your module with Drush.

You need to create a `drush` folder within your custom module and create a `YOURMODULE.drush.inc` file inside with appropriate Drush hooks.

Here's an example code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drush_command().
 */
function boilerplate_drush_command() {
  $items['boilerplate-hello'] = array(
    'callback' => 'boilerplate_hello_command',
    'description' => dt('Sample Drush command for boilerplate module.'),
    'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUSH,
    'arguments' => array(
      'name' => dt('Optional. A name which will be greeted upon running the command.'),
    ),
    'aliases' => array('boilerplate-hi'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_drush_help().
 */
function boilerplate_drush_help($section) {
  switch ($section) {
    case 'drush:boilerplate-hello':
      return dt('Sample Drush command for boilerplate module. It will just greet you, optionally with a name you provided.');
  }
}

/**
 * Command to download the Chosen plugin.
 */
function boilerplate_hello_command() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $name = (!empty($args[0])) ? $args[0] : FALSE;

  if ($name) {
    drush_log(dt('Hello @name!', array('@name' => $name)), 'success');
  }
  else {
    drush_log(dt('Hello there!'), 'success');
  }
}
```

This will allow you to run the command using `drush boilerplate-hello` or `drush boilerplate-hi` (alias). If you pass an argument, for example `drush boilerplate-hello ninjascorner` it will take it as an argument, which is the functionality you need.

This is taken from [my Drupal module boilerplate](https://github.com/topsitemakers/drupal7-boilerplate/blob/master/drush/boilerplate.drush.inc). The Drush integration from there is working, so you can install the module and play around with it to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer Topsitemakers. However, I wanted to read deployment.drushrc.php for example where users can put the configurations like repo URL, target directory to put the code from repository. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome; however I still didn't quite get what you are trying to do. What is the reason you can't put the repo URL in the `module.drush.inc` file? Or are you speaking about Drush make file by any chance?

Comment: The reason I can put the repo url in module.drush.inc is because I dont want other people to edit the module. I am planning to contribute this module to the community and it is not a good idea to put the config in the module. BTW this is a deployment module.

Comment: If you don't want others to edit the config, just hardcode it in constants within the module. That's a perfectly valid way to do it. If you want to contribute this, you can explain exactly what you are trying to achieve/what is the purpose so others can suggest you the best solution.